# Корректно ли предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Корректно ли предложение: «Нелогичным и, наверное, не совсем справедливым выглядит решение законодателя об освобождении от уголовной ответственности для основного и квалифицированного составов, предусмотренных ст. 1853 УК РФ, и невозможности этого по отношению к другим квалифицированным составам, вытекающим из перечня преступлений, приведенных в ч. 3 ст. 281 и ч.2 ст. 761 УК РФ»?

Answer (score 1):

Это предложение некорректно по той простой причине, что оно слишком замысловато построено. В предложении не менее 35 слов. Но это простое осложнённое предложение с одним(!) глаголом - сказуемым (причём это всего лишь глагол-связка)и с семью (!) осложняющими конструкциями, переплетёнными между собой. Восприятию смысла предложения мешает также обилие специальной лексики и лексики с отвлечённым значением.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, оно не корректно. Если отбросить лишнее (то, что не вызывает вопросов в этом предложении), оставив только непонятные места, получаем: *"...не совсем справедливым выглядит решение законодателя об освобождении от уголовной ответственности... и невозможности этого по отношению к другим квалифицированным составам"*. Невозможности чего? Непонятно. Местоимение взято с потолка, поэтому смысл предложения непонятен. Следовательно, перед нами некорректное предложение.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, чтобы предложение стало корректным, нужно исправить *невозможности* на *невозможность*. То есть кого-то освобождают от уголовной ответственности, что предусмотрено ст. 1853 УК, а кого-то нет. 
*Нелогичным... выглядит решение... об освобождении от уголовной ответственности и невозможность этого по отношению к другим квалифицированным составам...*

Comment: Местоимение "этого" к чему относится?

Comment: Этого - освобождения от уголовной ответственности.

Answer (score 0):

Корректно. Конечно, с непривычки очень тяжело читается, но грамматических недоразумений я не наблюдаю.

Если очень придираться, то, возможно, лучше 1) заменить "этого" на "такого освобождения" 2) привести к единому виду "для" и "по отношению". А вообще-то лучше всего у "целевой аудитории" поинтересоваться.

Answer (score 0):

Если "другие квалифицированные составы **вытекают** из перечня преступлений", которые кое-кто "привёл в ч. 3 ст. 128 и ч. 2 ст. 761 УК РФ", тогда упомянутый "перечень" "выглядит" "логичным и, наверное, совсем справедливым" **источником** по меньшей мере одного "другого квалифицированного состава".

Если "другие квалифицированные составы" **выезжают** "из перечня преступлений", которые кое-кто "привёл в ч. 3 ст. 128 и ч. 2 ст. 761 УК РФ", тогда переименование упомянутого  "перечня преступлений" в **депо правонарушений** есть "решение" "логичное и, наверное, совсем справедливое".

Если "другие квалифицированные составы вытекают из перечня преступлений", которые кое-кто "**привёл** в ч. 3 ст. 128 и ч. 2 ст. 761 УК РФ", тогда "логично и, наверное, совсем справедливо" оформить их **привод** надлежащим образом.

Comment: О великий, могучий русский язык!:))

Comment: >>>Если "другие квалифицированные составы вытекают из перечня преступлений",  
   
Скорее всего они там перечислены, но не уверен, возможно, что именно "вытекают", т.е. выводятся путём логических построений.  

Остальное - см. Ларf.

Comment: Часто легче заново построить фразу, чем пытаться ее откорректировать. Но для этого надо понимать суть высказывания.